# Zonal Statistics loop using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I am trying to loop the `arcpy.sa.ZonalStatistics` to calculate the mean of multiple raster files. When I'm trying the code for single file it's working perfectly fine. But when I try to loop it. ArcPy says `"RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool".`

Here is the script used:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

# set workspace and input folder
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:/2019"
input_folder = arcpy.env.workspace

# read vector
shp = ("D:/inventory/sub_basin_igb.shp")


# set the output folder
output_folder = r"D:/loop_zonal"
if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

# pathway to all rasters in workspace directory
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif*')
for raster in rasters:
zonal_stats = arcpy.sa.ZonalStatistics(shp, "L3_Name", raster, statistics_type="MEAN",
                                      ignore_nodata="DATA")
```

Comment: Try taking the brackets off where you set `shp`? Also your call to the zonal stats tool needs to be indented as its part of the for loop.

Comment: I think you should specify all parameter names (or none, dont mix). `arcpy.sa.ZonalStatistics(in_zone_data=shp, zone_field="L3_Name", in_value_raster=raster, statistics_type="MEAN", ignore_nodata="DATA")`